# Rails 3: cancel insert on after_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rollback, after-save

I have a model that, when a record is inserted, needs to call a webservice.

If the webservice fails ( timeout or other failures ), them the save in database should also be reverted.

I used the after_save callback and tried to raise an ActiveRecord::Rollback when this kind of error happens.

Although it returns false on object.save, it doesn't rollback the transaction. What is the proper way of doing this?

How can i also make sure that the record won't be created?

Answer (score 1):

Are you wrapping this in an Active Record Transaction block?

```
User.transaction do
  User.create(:username => 'Kotori')
  User.transaction(:requires_new => true) do
    User.create(:username => 'Nemu')
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

Also See:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `before_save` and return false from it.

Comment: You can check `id` presense in model. `id` will be present only after inserting to the database.